# Is this powdery mildew on my tomato?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, tomatoes, fungus

Just noticed this on my store bought plant (not grown from seed). It's now fruiting, and I don't see any white spots on the leaves.

[image: original stem]

Update: 25 Feb 2016 with close up of the stems and an more distant view of the plant health

[image: close up of affected stems]

[image: plant health]

Comment: Installed imgur app so I can upload an image, but doesn't seem to be working

Comment: No need to install an app to upload the image, but I see it fine.

Comment: I can't see a way to upload an image from an android device. So had to find a free web service, which meant installing another app.

Comment: Ah, okay. I understand

Comment: Are you referring to the patchy ghosting on the lower stem?

Comment: Yes, seems to be creeping up both main stems

Answer (score 6):

That appears to be Southern Blight, [*Sclerotium rolfsii*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athelia_rolfsii)

It's a fungal disease from the soil, and affects many species of plants. You cannot cure plants infected with it. From the [University of California](http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/PMG/r783100711.html):

> - Rotate to nonhost crops, such as corn, sorghum, rice, or small grains, for at least 2 years to reduce inoculum.
> - Deep plowing to bury plant refuse may help to destroy sclerotia.
> - Keeping the tops of beds dry in tomato fields helps reduce the disease in furrow- and buried-drip-irrigated fields.

For potted plants, I'd recommend disposing of the potting medium, and sterilizing or disposing of the container.

[image]

Comment: "tomato plants with southern blight have lesions on the stem at or near the soil line. These lesions develop rapidly, girdling the stem and resulting in a sudden and permanent wilting of the plant. White mats of mycelia are produced on the stem and in the adjacent soil. In a few days, tan to brown spherical sclerotia about 0.06 inch (0.5 mm) in diameter appear on the mycelial mat. The abundant sclerotia are a good diagnostic feature." I'm not seeing a white mycelium mat on the soil, no sclerotia, and no wilting though the leaves are slightly curled.

Comment: @GrahamChiu you're right.. I didn't see your picture well from my phone. Do you mind getting a closeup of the affected area?

Comment: I'm back at home so can provide the closer image

Comment: The plant survived to the end of summer/early autumn and I got a few tomatoes off it.  But it succumbed to scale attack.